# How to split the input_data using python?

Tags: python, regex, split

**UPDATED QUESTION**

```
input_data = 'ABCD:Data ScientistPBCD:Python Developer QBCD:Artificial IntelligenceBCD:Machine Learning Developer'

tag_list = ["ABCD", "BCD", "PBCD", "QBCD"]
```

Split the above input data using the tag_list

```
for each_tag in tag_list:
    input_data = input_data.replace(each_tag, "|" + each_tag)

print(input_data)
```

I got the below error output when i executing the above code

```
Error Output:-
|A|BCD:Data Scientist|P|BCD:Python Developer |Q|BCD:Artificial Intelligence|BCD:Machine Learning Developer
```

I am expecting the below output:-

```
Expected Output :-
|ABCD:Data Scientist|PBCD:Python Developer |QBCD:Artificial Intelligence|BCD:Machine Learning Developer
```

How to solve the above error?

Please Check the below code:-
I have tested the all code i got the error when new data comes in picture

```
import re

input_data = 'ABCD:AKSHAYTAB:INDIAN ARMYWXYZ:1234-M234656VXYZ:45666Gb4565UXYZ:45535353TIME:17:20OBTRL:346644MNP2:PUNE UNIVERCITYMNP3:SATARA PUNEMNP6:46564PQR2:AMAR GODASEEPQR3:PUNE 3545 LIIS1:467574IIS2:BANK OF INDIAABK1:56365ABK2:KOREGAON SATARAMTL: BEM:56546445745/PPI:MMC:AJINKYA DALAVI.FFC XYZ: SUMIT GODASE SATARAPPI:CNF:ANTARES HOLDINGS LP/AC-50293315'

tag_list = ["ABCD", "TAB", "WXYZ", "VXYZ", "UXYZ", "TIME", "OBTRL", "MNP2", "MNP3", "MNP6", "PQR2", "PQR3", "OGB3", "IIS1", "IIS2", "ABK1", "ABK2", "MTL", "BEM", "PPI", "MMC", "XYZ", "PPI", "CNF"]

for each_tag in tag_list:
 print(each_tag)
 input_data = re.sub(r"(?<![A-Z])"+each_tag, "|" + each_tag, input_data)

print(input_data)
```

Please Check the below image i have yellow highlighted the part that is not splittted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk2JH.png)

Comment: Instead of splitting, just match using [`[APQ]?BCD:(?:(?![APQ]?BCD:)[\s\S])*`](https://regex101.com/r/jAFoxf/1)

Comment: I am not used the regex please check the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tags are exhaustive, here's what you can do:

```
import re

input_data = 'ABCD:Data ScientistPBCD:Python Developer QBCD:Artificial IntelligenceBCD:Machine Learning Developer'

tag_list = ["ABCD", "BCD", "PBCD", "QBCD"]
pattern = r'([A|P|Q]{0,1}BCD)'
subbed_data = re.sub(pattern, r'|\1', input_data)

>>>subbed_data
'|ABCD:Data Scientist|PBCD:Python Developer |QBCD:Artificial Intelligence|BCD:Machine Learning Developer'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method

this regex will match the desired things

```
([A-Z]+?(?=:))
```

And replace with `!\1`

- `([A-Z]+?(?=:))` - Match A to Z one or more time, which is followed by `:`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/PKB2iU/2/)

Comment: Every time tag squence is jumpled up.

Comment: @Akshay this is a generic one. i see a pattern that all tags are capital letters followed by `:`. this regex matches that pattern. it will work even if the tags are jumbled up. if the pattern i see is stays the same for tag capital letters followed by `:`

Comment: @ Code maniac I know it works well but i want to solve the above probe using the code which i have created. Is there any solution from you?